# Angular/Webpack not binding styleUrls to component

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular, webpack

I'm trying to create my first Angular2 project and got stuck in a really stupid thing. I am using:

```
"@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
"webpack": "^2.2.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
```

webpack.config contents:

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: { 'polyfills': './angularApp/polyfills.ts', 'vendor': './angularApp/vendor.ts', 'app': './angularApp/main.ts'},
    output: { path: __dirname + '/wwwroot/', filename: 'dist/[name].bundle.js', chunkFilename: 'dist/[id].chunk.js', publicPath: '/' },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'] },
    devServer: { historyApiFallback: true, contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/'), watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 }},
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: "style-loader", use: { loader: "css-loader", options: { sourceMap: true }} }) }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills'] }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./wwwroot/dist', './wwwroot/assets']),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '[name].css', allChunks: true }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ filename: 'index.html', inject: 'body', template: 'angularApp/index.html' }),
    ]
};
```

The component reference in the app HTML:

```
<div class='col-sm-3'>
    <navigation></navigation>
</div>
```

navigation.component.css contents:

```
li.link-active a,
li.link-active a:hover,
li.link-active a:focus {
    background-color: #4189C7;
    color: white;
}
```

And finally navigation.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'navigation',
    templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css'.toString()]
})
export class NavigationComponent { }
```

**The problem**:

Build runs without any errors, but the component styles are applied globally and are not specific to the component. Inspecting the HTML I notice there are unique identifiers on the tags, but not on CSS. 
However if I place the css like this

```
//styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
    styles: [`
li.link-active a,
li.link-active a:hover,
li.link-active a:focus {
    background-color: #4189C7;
    color: white;
}`]
```

the styles are applied only to the component as intended and receive the unique identifiers. The problem is project wide so I suspect an error in the configuration. Honestly I am totally lost and have spent so much time on this that I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Before you bash me for the .toString() part from the component, please note that if I remove it I get the following error in the console "Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings" (that being my second problem)

Comment: Use your selector navigation{ .. your styles }

Comment: your answer seems pretty vague. Can you please elaborate? If I use a selector inside the css it defeats the whole purpose of creating separate  code for the component.

Comment: I'll link you to this might be a good reference: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js In my previous comment I suggested you wrap your css with the selector so the styles will be unique only per component. I don't seem to understand how you say its exactly the opposite

Comment: Thank you very much. This pointed me in the right direction. The webpack config was wrong so I used the suggested tempalte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe your webpack config is not correct.
You should distinguish between global styles and component styles, like this.
[image]

and if you are trying to create your first Angular2 project,I suggest you may reference this project.
https://github.com/ntesmail/angular2-webpack-template

Comment: In the end, I also think that was the case. I used that template suggested and everything worked perfectly fine. Thank you

Comment: my porject add【shark-angular2】 support yesterday  （^_^ ），which reference to [ http://shark.mail.netease.com/shark-angular2/index.html ] . Hope it helps you and  you will like it 。

Comment: would be nice if you could also add the code as text ;D

Comment: Which one is global which one is local in the above code?

Comment: @Dynamic The top one is global (we exclude any app specific files) and the bottom one is component specific (we look within the app directory).

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar issue to this based on JavaScript dependencies...

I built a JHipster application (with Webpack 4x) and then upgraded `css-loader` (and other JS packages) from `3.6.0` to `4.3.0` to ensure I'm only the latest versions of all JS dependencies.

This broke the component styles using `stylesUrl`.

After experimenting with some version locking, I found locking the `css-loader` package back at version `3.6.0` fixed this issue.

In `package.json`:

```
"css-loader": "3.6.0",
```

Then run `yarn install` followed by `yarn start` (or `npm`)

If it is not working correctly, then the `<style>` elements inside the `<head>` of the page will not be present or corrupted. In the browser you might see: `<head> ... <style>[object Module]</style> ... </head>`.

[image: broken styles]

Comment: Looks like there are breaking changes on `v4.0.0` (which also doesn't work) - perhaps it is one of those! https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/compare/v3.6.0...v4.0.0

Comment: Looking for a 2021 solution :)

Comment: With css-loader >=4 use 'raw-loader', 'extract-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'